# Polygon problem with Wacom on QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, tablet

I currently have a problem on QGIS with my Wacom tablet and polygonal tools.

When I create a shape with the polygonal tool, if I use my Wacom tablet, the cursor moves well, but the path (red dotted) that represents the next potential point does not follow the cursor. While it works perfectly with the mouse.

I made a short video to illustrate the problem: https://vimeo.com/333824677

Is it a bug or a configuration problem?
Is it possible to solve this problem? I would be much faster with my pen tablet.

- QGIS 3.6
- Mac Pro 2013 + OS X 10.13.6
- Wacom Intuos Pro (PTH-860) + 6.3.33-5
- Logitech G502.

Comment: When you use your mouse, there is always an connection to the graphic of the node you're about to draw. When using the pen, if you have the pen too far from the screen, there is no connection, so nothing shows on the screen. Could that be the issue? And I can't remember if there is a threshold / sensitivity you can set to control that distance...

Comment: Do you have this problem when creating lines, or only polygons?

Comment: I just watched the video. It looks like you're able to create a polygon with the pen, even though the rubberband doesn't track with the pen. So I guess I'm not sure what the problem is. Do you actually need to see the rubberband while digitizing?

Comment: @csk Yes, I need the elastic band to improve the accuracy of raster digitizing. and yes, I have the same problem with the lines.

Comment: @DPSSpatial It is not a problem of distance between the tip and the tablet (if this were the case, the cursor would not move).